# Unable to add phone number for 2 factor authentication in Facebook Meta Business Suite - 'Please enter a valid phone number' error

Tags: facebook

I'm currently experiencing an issue while trying to log into the Meta Business Suite. I enabled "2-factor authentication for everyone," and as a result, I was logged out of my account. Upon trying to access the suite again, I was prompted to select an authentication method. There were three options available, which I'll outline below:

- Authentication App: Facebook recommended this method, but when I clicked on it, I received the following error message: "The content you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may have expired, or you may not have permission to view this page." I attempted this for two consecutive days, but the error persisted.
- Text Message (SMS): I tried entering my 10-digit phone number (ensuring it was correct), but I continuously received the error message "Please enter a valid phone number." Initially, I assumed that the country code was unnecessary since it was already selected in the first input field. However, when I tried including the country code as well, I encountered the same error. Additionally, there was a warning stating that repeated entry of an "invalid number" may result in account restrictions. I even attempted again after waiting for a day, but the issue remained unresolved.

I couldn't find any helpful information online regarding this problem, and the error message itself is not very informative.

- Security Key: Unfortunately, I don't have permission to use this method.

Although i still have access to developers account, it's crucial for me to access the business suite as well in order to create system users and perform other necessary tasks.

I'm hopeful that someone in the community can provide assistance or guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Hi, Anurag. Yes, technically, I didn't solve the issue; it resolved itself one day when I tried it and it showed the registered number to send the OTP to. Then everything got sorted out. It was probably a bug, I think.